# Insert data into DB

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, odbc

I used MVC ASP.NET to create a form. I wanted to filter data such that when I enter a text in the box and search, values in the drop down are filtered. It's working fine when I search, drop down is filtered, but when I enter other details in the form and hit submit, these values don't get stored in DB.

```
<form>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" name="txtOne" />
    <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Whereas, when I remove the `<form>` tag, I'm not able to filter but values are getting stored in DB. I wonder where I'm going wrong.

Everything works just fine except for this.

Screen shots:

**With form tag**

[image: When I search for "AG" with <form> tag:]

**Without form tag**

[image: When I search for "AG" without <form> tag:]

I would like to filter the drop down and then store the form values in DB. Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Before reading anything in the question REMOVE THAT SQL INJECTION!!!

Comment: @FilipCordas my bad

Comment: [Here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-jQuery-AutoComplete-TextBox-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) a short tutorial on something similar to what you are trying to do

Comment: @FilipCordas Thanks man! :)